# Webscraping using Beautifulsoup 4 - extracting contact info

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[screenshot of html code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MbDS0.png)

This is my first post, please forgive me if I break some rules.
Im trying to webscrape vendor information using code which looks like

```
  soup.find_all('span', class_ = "class-name")
```

Please refer to the image attached.
I wanted to get the contact number but it is not given as text or something similar. Each digit seems to be in its own class tag and even inside that the digit isnt in text. Im also not familiar with webdev so if anyone could give suggestions I would really appreciate it.

url : https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Sunrise-Enterprises-Budhwar-Peth/020PXX20-XX20-130817131104-Z3I2_BZDET?xid=UHVuZSBFbGVjdHJvbmljIENvbXBvbmVudCBEZWFsZXJz

another similar page with multiple contact details is : https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Galaxy-Enterprises-And-Electronics-Behind-Bharti-Vidyapeeth-Near-Ichapurti-Mandir-Ambegaon-Budruk/020PXX20-XX20-140930130951-K4X6_BZDET?xid=UHVuZSBFbGVjdHJvbmljIENvbXBvbmVudCBEZWFsZXJz

Thanks

Comment: could you write here full URL please?

Comment: The `::before` CSS [pseudo-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements) is used on each `<span>` element to actually render the number. Value of `::before` is based on the span CSS class, which I suspect changes. That's a common technique for preventing scrapping and bots.

Comment: Do you think there is a workaround or is it not possible to get with Beautifulsoup ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second style tag contains css code in which the [sequence](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/justdial-phone-number-anbu-saravanan?articleId=6633570170688372736) of the icon-xx properties defines which number the property matches with. This is used to load an image with this number on the webpage, so there are no numbers to scrape. The solution is to 1) map the icon-xx properties to numbers based on their sequence in the css string; 2) find the phone number spans in the html body and retrieve the matching numbers:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.justdial.com/Pune/Sunrise-Enterprises-Budhwar-Peth/020PXX20-XX20-130817131104-Z3I2_BZDET?xid=UHVuZSBFbGVjdHJvbmljIENvbXBvbmVudCBEZWFsZXJz'
r = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent' : "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)"})
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

text = soup.find_all('style', {"type": "text/css"}, text=True)[1]
data = text.contents[0].split('smoothing:grayscale}', 1)[1].split('\n')[0]
icon_items = [i.split(':')[0] for i in data.split('.') if len(i)>0]
items = ['0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','+','-',')','(']
full_list = dict(zip(icon_items, items))

phone_numbers = soup.find_all('span',{'class':'telnowpr'})
for i in phone_numbers:
    numbers = i.find_all('span')
    number = [full_list[y.attrs['class'][1]] for y in numbers]
    print("phone number: " + ''.join([str(elem) for elem in number]) )
```

Result:

```
phone number: 07947197693
phone number: 07947197693
phone number: 07947197693
```